# Python request token authentication to a server 401 error

Tags: json, python-3.x, post, python-requests, request

I am trying to connect a server that accepts JSON as input and returns JSON.
But I am getting 401 what am I missing?

```
headers = CaseInsenstiveDict()
headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer {ey... (I copied token here)}"
//other headers
headers["Content-type"] = "application/json"
headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
data = """
JSON file
"""
resp = requests.post("URL", headers=headers, data=data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others that may have the same issue as me:
It seems for OAuth 2.0 Authorization we need to remove {}. After I removed it from the string I got the response.
headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer ey..." ey... is the token

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following:

- Convert `data` to a python `dict` structure like `data = {'foo': 'bar', 'eggs': {'a': 123, 'baz': True, 'wow': None}}`. If your actual data is a .json file, load it properly:

```py
import json
with open('file.json') as f:
   data = json.load(f)
```

- Use `json=data` parameter in request:

```py
resp = requests.post("URL", headers=headers, json=data)
```

- Do NOT specify request content type:

```py
# remove this row, requests will adjust this header automatically
headers["Content-type"] = "application/json"
```

Comment: thanks the real file is a very big one and I wanted to check if I could connect to the server with one single row before continuing with this: 
data = """
JSON file
"""